# Implement Underscore.js in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, underscore.js

First I install underscore dependencies ( npm install underscore) and after that I imported in this file. So I justo want in my console to use _.where method to get just object with this tittle. I will show in my code.

> But I get error Can't find variable: _

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Appbar, Title, TextInput, Button, Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native'; 
import Header from './Header'
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { where } from 'underscore';

export default Search = ({navigation})=>{
    const [city, setCity] = useState('')
    const [cities, setCities]=useState([])
    const fetchCities = (text)=>{
        setCity(text)
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(item=>item.json())
        .then(cityData=>{
            console.log(_.where(cityData, {title: "qui est esse"}))
        })
    }

    const btnClick = ()=>{
        navigation.navigate("Kuca", {city:city})
    }
    const listClick = (cityName) => {
        setCity(cityName)
        navigation.navigate("Kuca", {city:cityName})
    }
    return (
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
         <Header name = "Search Screen"/>
         <Text>SearchScreen</Text>
         <TextInput label='city name' 
         theme={{colors:{primary:"#00aaff"}}}
         value={city}
         onChangeText={(text)=>fetchCities(text)}
         ></TextInput>
          <Button 
          icon="content-save"
           mode="contained"
           theme={{colors:{primary:"#00aaff"}}}
           style={{margin:20}}
           onPress={() => btnClick()}>
            <Text style={{color:"white"}}>Pritisni me</Text>        
        </Button> 
        <FlatList
        data={cities}
        renderItem= {({item})=>{
            return(
                <Card
                style={{margin:2, padding:12}}
                onPress = {()=>listClick()}
                >    
                    <Text>madrid</Text>
                </Card>
            )
        }}
         keyExtractor = {item=>item.body}
        />
     </View>
    );
}
```

Can someone help to fix this?

Comment: You directly import underscore.js' `where` function, so you can just omit the `_.` part.

Comment: Try to add `import _ from 'underscore'`

Answer (score 1):

You are directly import the `where` method. So you should use it like:

```
console.log(where(cityData, { title: "qui est esse" }));
```